# How to find the original directory where the app was launched from while the app is in a different directory

Tags: c#

I am using the command line to launch an app, which is in a different folder than the current directory as it's shown on the command prompt:

**C:\BPS >** "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\myapp\myapp.EXE"

What I need to know is that how to find out the **C:\BPS** as soon as my app launches. In other words, how can find the initial directory from which the command to launch my app was triggered?

I have tried **Environment.CurrentDirectory**, **GetCurrentDirectory** and a few other methods, but all I am getting is ***C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\myapp***

Thank You

Comment: Weird... Is it a normal console app? `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is working fine for me when I call an app from elsewhere in the command prompt.

Comment: Yes, it is a very simple console app. I tried it again but still, shows the location of my app and not the current path.

Comment: If you create a brand new empty console app with the *only* line of code in `Main` being `Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);` and then run from the command prompt, you're still seeing the path to the app, not the working directory?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb as you suggested I created a console app and launch it and Environment.CurrentDirectory returned the correct directory. Thank you. I will review my original app to see if anything is out of line.

Comment: I found the issue in the code. The **Environment.CurrentDirectory** had been initialized and so what it returned was the default folder!

Comment: Feel free to post what you've discovered as an answer. Who knows, maybe someone else will run into the same problem.